Difference between effective and physical address
I am learning assembly programming on the 8086 microprocessor, and I would like to understand the difference between the effective address and the physical address
My teacher said that the effective address and physical address are the same, but other references say that the effective address is the offset.

Effective address is the offset, yes. Physical and linear are the same in 8086 real mode.

Although all of the registers in the 8086 are limited to 16 bits, the amount of memory that an 8086 can address is 1 MB. That's a 20-bit quantity.
The CPU solves this by always combining two 16-bit values in a way that it produces a 20-bit address. One of the constituting 16-bit values is the effective address that the instruction at hand calculates based on the involved addressing mode. The other 16-bit value comes from one of the segment registers (CS, DS, ES, or SS). The segment register's value is multiplied by 16, and the effective address is added to it. This yields a 20-bit value that we call the physical address aka the linear address.
It is easy to understand that once a certain segment has been selected (by loading a 16-bit value in a segment register), the effective address can also be seen as on offset in that particular segment.
Load Effective Address
That the effective address is what the instruction at hand calculates based on the involved addressing mode is already in the name of the LEA instruction that does just that. It Loads the Effective Address.

In Intel's manuals, an EA is the offset part of an addressing mode.  It doesn't include segment base.
What is an effective address? quotes a relevant section.
The LEA (Load Effective Address) instruction's behaviour matches this definition:
lea si, [bx+1] just sets AX = BX+1 (the effective address).
It doesn't add the DS segment base.  (If it did, that would make it less useful for address calculations, because a later mov al, [si] will add the segment base again.)
Your teacher might be using different terminology (accidentally or on purpose), or simplifying for the case where the segment base is 0.  Or if they had learn this ancient obsolete version of a still-widely-used architecture in order to teach a class, maybe they were more familiar with modern x86.  Segment bases are all 0 under mainstream OSes in 32-bit mode, and always in 64-bit mode except with FS or GS segments.  This gives a flat memory model where linear = offset = effective address, and you can address all of linear address-space that way.

A seg:off logical address translates to a linear address as seg_base + offset, on all versions of x86.
8086 doesn't have protected mode so seg_base is always seg_register << 4 (shift left by one hex digit.)  On later CPUs, writing a segment register updates the internal "descriptor cache" with a new base address, in a way that depends on what mode the CPU was in when you did it. In real mode, writing an Sreg works the same as it did on 8086, setting base = Sreg<<4.
8086 doesn't have paging, so linear addresses are physical.
Physical address-space contains DRAM, and also device memory like video RAM, and MMIO for devices that use that instead of in / out IO address-space.   Some of physical address-space might not be backed by anything, in a machine with less than the maximum amount of RAM.
8086 only has 20 address lines, so the addresses calculation wraps around for high addresses like FFFF:FFFF, aliasing the same linear addresses in the first 64K as 0000:FFEF.  (Later CPUs have wider logical addresses, and external hardware, the "A20 Gate", could emulate that wrapping for compatibility on later IBM-PC compatible machines.  OSes have to turn it off to use all the RAM on machines with more than 1 MiB.)

See also Find Segment address from given physical and effective address for an example of address calculation, and of reversing it given a linear address and offset.

The x86 architecture has three stages of address computation:
In the first stage, the effective address is computed.  This address is the result of performing the computation given by the memory operand's addressing mode, i.e. index is multiplied by scale and added to base and displacement to produce an address.  If you use the lea (load effective address) instruction, this is the address that is computed.  For example, if you have a memory operand of [eax + 2*ecx + 1] with eax = 0x1000 and ecx = 0x100, the effective address will be 0x1000 + 2*0x100 + 1 = 0x1201.
In the second stage, the segment descriptor cache is queried to apply the segment base address of the segment the memory operand accesses to the effective address, forming a linear address  (as in, not segmented).  The default segment for segment depends on the base register used.  If the base register is rbp or rsp (or a differently sized variant of these), the ss segment is the default, otherwise the ds segment is the default.  Some instructions with implicit memory operands have other defaults (e.g. stos and movs, which use es for the destination).  The segment can be overridden using a segment prefix.
For example, if your memory operand is the same as above and the base address of segment ds is 0x1000, the linear address will be 0x1000 + 0x1201 = 0x2201.
This step can usually be ignored.  In long (64 bit) mode, the base addresses configured for cs, ds, ss, and es are ignored.  In 32 bit mode, they are usually set to zero.  The base addresses of fs and gs are however often set to some nonzero value to facilitate the use of thread-local storage.  If you see an fs or gs segment override, that's a strong indicator of TLS being used.
In the third step, the linear address is looked up in the TLB, or failing that, in the page table to form a physical address.  This address is then used to access memory.  The physical addresses are managed by your operating system.  You can generally ignore this step too.
If virtualisation is used, there may be an additional translation step to translate virtualised physical addresses to physical addresses.  This is called nested paging.  When accessing device memory, there may also be an additional step of address translation as part of an IOMMU, translating virtual device addresses to physical device addresses.
Memory address translation can fail at all but the first of these stages.  When computing the linear address, the segment could be not present or not of the right type or the segment limit could be exceeded or access rights could be insufficient.  When computing physical addresses, the page could be not present or not accessible.  The same applies to nested paging or the IOMMU.

The OP is asking about 8086 specifically.  It doesn't have paging, so it stops after seg_base + offset.  And it doesn't support protected mode, so the segment base is always seg_reg << 4, rather than being a descriptor "cache".
